# After Effects: Jagged edges on shape layer and white borders in general

Tags: after-effects, shape

The two white shapes are virtually the same but on different layers in picture 1. I don't know why I'm getting these jagged edges on one of them. I've already toggled 'quality and sampling' but it doesn't fix it. I tought it was just a preview issue but they end up being rendered like this.

It happens in another comp also, but in footage's borther (picture 2).

I'm using after effects CC 2017

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Is the footage interlaced? Are you rendering interlaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's embarrasing, but it was a blending mode issue.

I must have accidentaly fiddled with blending and couldnt percieve it.

sorry for the dumbness.